# Flatten nested dictionary - convert list element to string

Tags: python, dictionary, nested

I have a nested dictionary where the lowest level consists of a list with one element each. I want to change this level from list to string.
Assume I have a dictionary such as this:

```
dict = {id1:{'key11':['value11'],'key12':['value12']}, id2:{'key21':['value21'],'key22':['value22']}}
```

How can I get:

```
dict = {id1:{'key11': 'value11','key12':'value12'}, id2:{'key21':'value21','key22':'value22'}}
```

Additional question:
How does the solution change if the keys and values do not follow a certain logic but each element is unique and you have many of them; such as in the below example:

```
dictionary = {'ida':{'abc':['def'],'fgh':['ijk'] (...)}, 'idb':{'lmn':['opq'],'rst':['uvw']} (...)}
```

Thank you!!

Note:
I get this structure because I am using a list/map structure earlier in the code to extract text from a XML file which yields list values.

```
get_text = lambda x: x.text
content = [list(map(get_text, i)) for i in content]
```

Comment: I don't think "extracting" is a great word for what you're doing here, it looks like you are trying to "flatten" a nested data structure.

Comment: Thanks I'll update the title. I was not sure how to call what I try to do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works:

```
dictionary = {'id1':{'key11':['value11'],'key12':['value12']}, 'id2':{'key21':['value21'],'key22':['value22']}}

new_dict = {key: {key1:value1[0] for key1, value1 in value.items()} for key, value in dictionary.items()}
new_dict
#{'id1': {'key11': 'value11', 'key12': 'value12'},
# 'id2': {'key21': 'value21', 'key22': 'value22'}}
```

Also, I would not use predefined terms like `dict`

Comment: Thanks! - what would you do if you have (many) keys and list elements that do not follow a logic such as above but are unique each and every element? ```dictionary = {'ida':{'abc':['def'],'fgh':[ijk']}, 'idb':{'lmn':[opq'],'rst':['uvw']}}```

Comment: Well, I would do the same. The code also works on your second example (if you correct string syntax)